# Undefined function for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: c++, matlab, function, undefined

I downloaded the MATLAB code from here http://cazencott.info/dotclear/public/code/scones.zip. When I run 'demo', it says "Undefined function 'maxflowmex' for input arguments of type 'double'". In fact there is only a c++ file "maxflowmex.cpp" in the folder (already added to path). Whether it needs a "maxflowmex.m" instead of "maxflowmex.cpp" to run properly? Or some other methods to call "maxflowmex.cpp"? Or I need to compile something?

Comment: *How* do you compile the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at the zip file.  There are MEX wrappers in the `maxflow` directory that are written where MATLAB calls these functions which are written in C, but are runnable in MATLAB.  These MEX wrappers need to be compiled using a compiler that is compatible for your operating system before you run them.

However, there are pre-compiled binaries, but I only see 64-bit binaries for Linux and Mac OS and  I don't see Windows binaries.  Because you can't run them, you are most likely running a **32-bit** operating system or Windows.  I suspect you are running either Windows or 32-bit Linux, as Mac OS by default ships out as 64-bit.

There is a `make.m` script that you need to run so that you can compile the `maxflow` library for your machine.  Once you compile the library, running `demo.m` should be successful.

Before you do that, you need to make sure you set up `mex` by doing `mex -setup` in the command window, then choose the right compiler.  Once you do this, run `make.m` that's inside the `maxflow` directory.

If you don't have a compiler, if you're using Linux, doing an `apt-get` on the `gcc` packages should be good enough, so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6-base g++-4.6 cpp-4.6 libgomp1 libquadmath0 libc6-dev
```

If you are using Windows, then the supported compiler that you need will depend on what version of MATLAB you are using.  I'm assuming you are using the latest one, and so downloading the latest version of Visual Studio Express as well as the SDK should be sufficient.

- http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758

Comment: Many thanks. I tried it on Linux-64 and it works